# Issue: $locationChangeStart is executing after page is redirected

Tags: angularjs

$locationChangeStart is executing after page is redirected. So even i get error message page will be already redirected. How can i make page redirect after it executes $locationChangeStart.

Below is the index.html page from where i am linking to 'Home' and 'About' page.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">   
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="homecontroller.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body ng-app="routerApp" ng-controller="homeCntrl">
    <form name="form.myForm">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div ui-view></div>
        </div>
        </form>
</body>
```

Below is the index.js page where i have written code to display error message

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
       .state('home', {
           url: '/home',
           templateUrl: 'home.html'
       })
        .state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: 'about.html'
        })
});

routerApp.controller('homeCntrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.$watch('form.myForm.$dirty', function (dirty) {
        if (dirty) {
            $rootScope.preventNavigation();
        }
        else {
            $rootScope.allowNavigation();
        }
    });

    $scope.form = {};
    $scope.Save = function () {
        alert('Save');
        $scope.form.myForm.$setPristine();
    }
}]);

routerApp.directive('confirmOnExit', function () {
    return {
        link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {
            window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                if ($scope.form.myForm.$dirty) {
                    return "The form is dirty, do you want to stay on the page?";
                }
            }
            $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
                if ($scope.form.myForm.$dirty) {
                    if (!confirm("The form is dirty, do you want to stay on the page?")) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Below is the home.html page

```
  Name: <input name="input" ng-model="myModel.text">
    <p>myModel.text = {{form.myModel.text}}</p>
    <p>$pristine = {{form.myForm.$pristine}}</p>
    <p>$dirty = {{form.myForm.$dirty}}</p>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="Save()">Save</button>
```

So in the above example, Now i am in 'Home' page and i have filled the input field and now my page is dirty. Now when i click on 'About' first it will redirect to 'About' page and then it will execute $locationChangeStart and it will display error code.
How to make error message display first before page is redirected.

below is the plunker (Note: ui-sref is not working here, but exact code working fine in my VS. I am not able to figure out why. But my problem is how to check $locationChangeStart  first and then redirect if it is not dirty)

https://plnkr.co/edit/LoGGusldqb74Zf5QGoOJ?p=preview

Comment: refer: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9921

Comment: not 100% sure I undestood the problem, but I think in `window.onbeforeunload` section you are not blocking the page with `event.preventDefault()` and you have to do it